# Как раскрыть меню bootstrap без дерганий пуктов меню?

Tags: css, bootstrap, bootstrap4

Есть меню `bootstrap 4`, которое в мобильной версии раскрывается по бутерброду.
Мне нужно задать отступ от верхнего края меню и в самих пунктах и чтобы при раскрытии меню ничего не дергалось, а плавно раскрывалось. Как это сделать?

**Код** [фидл](https://jsfiddle.net/motnsa2L/)

```css
#collapsibleNavbar {
    margin-top: 65px;
}
.navbar-light .show .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    padding-top: 17px;
    padding-bottom: 17px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EAEAEA;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="">
 Logo
 </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar" aria-controls="collapsibleNavbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> 
 </button>
    <div id="collapsibleNavbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Main</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <span class="subnav-item"><a class="dropdown-item" href="">List 1</a></span>
            <span class="subnav-item"><a class="dropdown-item" href="">List 2</a></span>
            <span class="subnav-item"><a class="dropdown-item" href="">List 3</a></span>
            <span class="subnav-item"><a class="dropdown-item" href="">List 4</a></span>
            <span class="subnav-item"><a class="dropdown-item" href="">List 5</a></span>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link link" href="#link2">Link 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link link" href="#link3">Link 3</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link link" href="#link4">Link 4</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Один из вариант](https://jsfiddle.net/ctzLa8gr/1/) "в лоб" это сразу задать margin для меню. Что он добавлялся не после раскрытия

```css
.navbar-toggler {
  margin-top: 65px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="">
 Logo
 </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar" aria-controls="collapsibleNavbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> 
 </button>
    <div id="collapsibleNavbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Main</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <span class="subnav-item"><a class="dropdown-item" href="">List 1</a></span>
            <span class="subnav-item"><a class="dropdown-item" href="">List 2</a></span>
            <span class="subnav-item"><a class="dropdown-item" href="">List 3</a></span>
            <span class="subnav-item"><a class="dropdown-item" href="">List 4</a></span>
            <span class="subnav-item"><a class="dropdown-item" href="">List 5</a></span>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link link" href="#link2">Link 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link link" href="#link3">Link 3</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link link" href="#link4">Link 4</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: и что вы с таким лбом решаете? Зачем сместили меню вниз?

Comment: Скорее всего я так понял вашу задачу. И видимо не правильно.